# invalid-dynamic-link-domain - Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to use the activation email link on localhost. But getting an error `auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain`. Here's my configuration which I later pass to `sendSignInLinkToEmail` method

```
 const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: 'exp://192.168.18.30:19001',
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOS: {
      bundleId: 'xxx.xxx.xxx'
    },
    android: {
      packageName: 'xxx.xxx.xxx'
      installApp: true,
      minimumVersion: '12'
    },
    dynamicLinkDomain: 'http://192.168.18.30:19001/activation'
  };
```

Im not sure If I understand correctly idea of dynamic link...But I can't skip this param

Comment: You might want to consider to reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly. There could be an underlying issue in your Dynamic Links that causes this error. It’ll be challenging to help you on a public forum without going into project-specific details. The support channel can offer personalized help.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting the same error. Did you figure out the solution?